# Yii Active Record adding multiple conditions in named scopes from different tables

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am trying to make a condition that the client ID must match the client ID and a region field in the locations table must match the region attached to the location id that is associated with the users location.

So I have 3 tables. The current table(t1), the table relation1 refers to (t2), and the table that t2 refers to in relation2 (we will call this t3).

```
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'with' => $rel,
        'condition'=>'relation1.client_id=:client_id AND
                      relation1.relation2.region=:region',
        'params'=>array(':client_id'=>$client_id, ':region'=>$region),
    ));

return $this;
```

Relation1 is the relation in the table once removed from this one. The table that relation1 refers to has a relation called relation2 that gets me to where I need to retrieve the region value.

If I remove the second condition and parameter it works, so I know relation1 is working, and relation2 also works in other contexts. Here they are if would like to see them.

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'relation1' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 't2', 't2_id'),
        );
    }
```

and

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'relation2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 't3', 't3_id'),
             );
    }
```

I really feel like this should work. Any help?

Comment: I may be wrong, but i guess this is exactly the case of bug which i reported on [Yii github repository](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/586). Check out the easy fix there, try if it helps you. If it does, then it's a bug and you should wait for 1.1.11 to come out and fix it.

Comment: I tried your patch to no avail. Thanks for the reply though. Any other thoughts? The error I get is that the relation1.relation2.region column cannot be found, but I don't know how to target it any other way.

Comment: Try relation2.region=:region ? Without relation1.

Comment: Yeah I tried that several times too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from another site. If you are interested, the solution is:

```
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
            'with' => array(
                'relation1' => array(
                       'condition' => 'relation1.column = :column_id', 
                       'params' => array(':column_id'=>$column_id)),
                'relation1.relation2' => array(
                       'condition' => 'relation2.column2 = :column2', 
                       'params' => array(':column2'=>$column2))
            ),
        ));
    return $this;
```

Thanks for your help!